# get the text instead of the value in select elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, codeigniter

Is there a way to get the text instead of the value on select elements and make a storage to pass it into $this->input->post('cols')?

here is my controller

```
public function index() {
    $data['title'] = 'Reports';
    $data['content'] = 'reports';
    $this->load->view('layout/admin_layout', $data);
}

public function gen_custom_rep() {
    $col_num = 1;
    $c_dt_st = explode("/", $this->input->post('c_dt_st'));
    $c_dt_end = explode("/", $this->input->post('c_dt_end'));
    $dt_st = $c_dt_st[2] . '-' . $c_dt_st[0] . '-' . $c_dt_st[1];
    $dt_end = $c_dt_end[2] . '-' . $c_dt_end[0] . '-' . $c_dt_end[1];
    $ref = $this->input->post('list_of');
    $oprtn = $this->input->post('oprtn');
    $val = $this->input->post('val');
    $columns = array("$ref");
    $qry = "SELECT DISTINCT($ref) as ref_col";
    foreach ($this->input->post('cols') as $col_nm) {
        $col_res = $this->m_reports->exec_custom("SELECT DISTINCT($col_nm) as col_key FROM tbl_proj_details");
        foreach ($col_res as $c_res) {
            array_push($columns, $c_res->col_key);
            $qry = $qry . ",(SELECT $oprtn($val) FROM tbl_proj_details WHERE $ref = ref_col AND $col_nm='$c_res->col_key' AND (dt_approved BETWEEN '$dt_st' AND '$dt_end')) as col_$col_num";
            $col_num = $col_num + 1;
        }
    }
    $qry = $qry . " FROM tbl_proj_details";
    $data['res'] = $this->m_reports->exec_custom($qry);
    $this->load->library('excel');
    $this->load->view('reports/report_excel', $data);
}

public function generate_imported() {
    $frm = $this->input->post('yr');
    $qry = "SELECT masterlist_id";

    foreach ($this->input->post('cols')as $col_nm) {
        $qry = $qry . ", " . $col_nm;
    }
    $qry = $qry . " FROM master_list WHERE date_approved LIKE '%$frm%'";
    $this->m_reports->exec_custom_array($qry);

    $this->load->library('excel');
    //Set Active Sheet
    $this->excel->setActiveSheetIndex(0);
    $this->excel->getActiveSheet()->setTitle('Core and Non Core');
    // Set Orientation, size and scaling
    $this->excel->getActiveSheet()->getPageSetup()->setOrientation(PHPExcel_Worksheet_PageSetup::ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
    $this->excel->getActiveSheet()->getPageSetup()->setPaperSize(PHPExcel_Worksheet_PageSetup::PAPERSIZE_A4);
    $this->excel->getActiveSheet()->getPageSetup()->setFitToPage(true);
    $this->excel->getActiveSheet()->getPageSetup()->setFitToWidth(1);
    $this->excel->getActiveSheet()->getPageSetup()->setFitToHeight(0);
    //Set Page Margins
    $this->excel->getActiveSheet()->getPageMargins()->setTop(0.75);
    $this->excel->getActiveSheet()->getPageMargins()->setRight(1.2);
    $this->excel->getActiveSheet()->getPageMargins()->setLeft(1.2);
    $this->excel->getActiveSheet()->getPageMargins()->setBottom(0.75);
    //Set Repeat Row
    $this->excel->getActiveSheet()->getPageSetup()->setRowsToRepeatAtTopByStartAndEnd(5, 6);

    $cls = $this->input->post('cols');
    array_unshift($cls, "ID");
    $this->make_row('A', 1, $cls);
    if (is_array($res)) {
        $r_nm = 2;
        foreach ($res as $r) {
            $cl_nm = 'A';
            foreach ($r as $flds) {
                $this->make_cell($flds, $cl_nm, $r_nm);
                $cl_nm++;
            }
            $r_nm++;
        }
    }

    $filename = 'SETUP_master_list.xlsx'; //save our workbook as this file name
    header('Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel'); //mime type
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="' . $filename . '"'); //tell browser what's the file name
    header('Cache-Control: max-age=0'); //no cache
    //save it to Excel5 format (excel 2003 .XLS file), change this to 'Excel2007' (and adjust the filename extension, also the header mime type)
    //if you want to save it as .XLSX Excel 2007 format
    $objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($this->excel, 'Excel2007');
    //force user to download the Excel file without writing it to server's HD
    $objWriter->save('php://output');
}

public function make_cell($cellvalue = 0, $hloc = 0, $vloc = 0, $colspan = 1, $rowspan = 1, $width = false, $bld = false, $centered = false, $perce = FALSE, $colr = FALSE, $fnt_size = 11) {
    $this->excel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue($hloc . $vloc, $cellvalue);
    $this->excel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle($hloc . $vloc)->getFont()->setSize($fnt_size);
    $this->excel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle($hloc . $vloc)->getFont()->setBold($bld);
    $hloc2 = $hloc;
    $vloc2 = $vloc;
    $styleArray = array('borders' => array('allborders' => array('style' => PHPExcel_Style_Border::BORDER_THIN)),);
    if ($colspan > 1 || $rowspan > 1) {
        while ($colspan > 1) {
            $hloc2++;
            $colspan--;
        }
        while ($rowspan > 1) {
            $vloc2++;
            $rowspan--;
        }
        $this->excel->getActiveSheet()->mergeCells($hloc . $vloc . ':' . $hloc2 . $vloc2);
        $this->excel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle($hloc . $vloc . ':' . $hloc2 . $vloc2)->applyFromArray($styleArray);
        $this->excel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle($hloc . $vloc . ':' . $hloc2 . $vloc2)->getAlignment()->setWrapText(true);
    }
    if ($centered == true) {
        $this->excel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle($hloc . $vloc)->getAlignment()->setHorizontal(PHPExcel_Style_Alignment::HORIZONTAL_CENTER);
    }
    if ($width != false) {
        $this->excel->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension($hloc)->setWidth($width);
    }
    if ($perce != false) {
        $this->excel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle($hloc . $vloc)->getNumberFormat()->applyFromArray(
                array(
                    'code' => PHPExcel_Style_NumberFormat::FORMAT_PERCENTAGE_00
                )
        );
    }
    if ($colr != FALSE) {
        $this->excel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle($hloc . $vloc)->getFill()->applyFromArray(array('type' => PHPExcel_Style_Fill::FILL_SOLID, 'startcolor' => array('rgb' => $colr)));
    }
    $this->excel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle($hloc . $vloc)->applyFromArray($styleArray);
    $this->excel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle($hloc . $vloc)->getAlignment()->setWrapText(true);
}

public function makeheader_noborder($cellvalue = 0, $hloc = 0, $vloc = 0, $colspan = 1, $rowspan = 1, $bld = false, $fnt_size = 11) {
    $this->excel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue($hloc . $vloc, $cellvalue);
    $this->excel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle($hloc . $vloc)->getFont()->setSize($fnt_size);
    $this->excel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle($hloc . $vloc)->getFont()->setBold($bld);
    $hloc2 = $hloc;
    $vloc2 = $vloc;
    if ($colspan > 1 || $rowspan > 1) {
        while ($colspan > 1) {
            $hloc2++;
            $colspan--;
        }
        while ($rowspan > 1) {
            $vloc2++;
            $rowspan--;
        }
        $this->excel->getActiveSheet()->mergeCells($hloc . $vloc . ':' . $hloc2 . $vloc2);
    }
    $this->excel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle($hloc . $vloc)->getAlignment()->setHorizontal(PHPExcel_Style_Alignment::HORIZONTAL_CENTER);
}

public function makecell_vertical($cellvalue = 0, $hloc = 0, $vloc = 0, $colspan = 1, $rowspan = 1, $width = false, $height = false, $bld = false, $fnt_size = 11) {
    $this->excel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue($hloc . $vloc, $cellvalue);
    $this->excel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle($hloc . $vloc)->getFont()->setSize($fnt_size);
    $this->excel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle($hloc . $vloc)->getFont()->setBold($bld);
    $this->excel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle($hloc . $vloc)->getAlignment()->setTextRotation(90);
    $hloc2 = $hloc;
    $vloc2 = $vloc;
    $styleArray = array(
        'borders' => array(
            'allborders' => array(
                'style' => PHPExcel_Style_Border::BORDER_THIN
            )
        ),
    );
    if ($colspan > 1 || $rowspan > 1) {
        while ($colspan > 1) {
            $hloc2++;
            $colspan--;
        }
        while ($rowspan > 1) {
            $vloc2++;
            $rowspan--;
        }
        $this->excel->getActiveSheet()->mergeCells($hloc . $vloc . ':' . $hloc2 . $vloc2);
        $this->excel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle($hloc . $vloc . ':' . $hloc2 . $vloc2)->applyFromArray($styleArray);
        $this->excel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle($hloc . $vloc . ':' . $hloc2 . $vloc2)->getAlignment()->setWrapText(true);
    }
    if ($width != false) {
        $this->excel->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension($hloc)->setWidth($width);
    }
    if ($height != false) {
        $this->excel->getActiveSheet()->getRowDimension($vloc)->setRowHeight($height);
    } else if ($height == false) {
        $this->excel->getActiveSheet()->getRowDimension($vloc)->setRowHeight(-1);
    }
    $this->excel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle($hloc . $vloc)->applyFromArray($styleArray);
    $this->excel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle($hloc . $vloc)->getAlignment()->setWrapText(true);
}

public function make_row($int_pos, $r_no, $arr, $width = FALSE) {
    if (is_array($arr)) {
        foreach ($arr as $cv) {
            $this->make_cell($cv, $int_pos, $r_no, 1, 1, $width, FALSE, FALSE);
            $int_pos++;
        }
    }
}

}
```

in my view page.

```
    <div class="form-group col-md-6 col-sm-12">
                    <label>Columns:(Ctrl+Click to Select Multiple)</label>
                    <select class="form-control" name="cols[]" multiple="multiple" id="cols[]" required="required">
                        <option value="latest_upd">Latest Update</option>
                        <option value="status">Status</option>
                        <option value="spin">SPIN</option>
                        <option value="file_location">File location</option>
                        <option value="upl_webgis">uploaded to webgis</option>
                        <option value="rem_upl">Remarks on upload</option>
                        <option value="level_approval">Level of Approval</option>
                        <option value="date_approved">Date Approved</option>
                        <option value="year_appr">Year Approved</option>
    </select>
```

Here. I just edited my post. :D does anyone knows how am I going to get the text from selected options and put it in a variable to pass it on the input post so I could use it as a column names to my generated excel file

Comment: you can't mix php and javascript...they run in different places at different times. javascript in browser, php on server

Comment: Provide full explanation of what you want to acheive

Comment: i have this code that generates to excel format. the value of each options from select elements corresponds to the tables in database. we name the table with shortcut names or something like this... in the table_name, instead of "Latest Update" we use latest_update. my code is already generating excel file but the output of excel, in column names it shows   | latest_update | spin | status |.

that is why I want to use the text from selected options instead of the value :)

Comment: sure seems simple enough to map these at server since you already map the text to put in the options against the values. What is process flow of the form submit and excel output?

Comment: just edited my post :D maybe it would help you to analyze the flow? :D

Comment: not asking about code...asking what objective is with this text array and what is being done with excel file. Is there more form to submit? This question is really lacking in details

Comment: the value of each options corresponds to the table from database that has data. so the process is, as the user selects options it would get the data from that database at the same time, instead of using the value as column names to the excel file, am asking if there's a way of using the text from the selected options instead of the value

Comment: We understand that...and do what with them? Put them into form? Can't put excel into browser so where is it going and when?

Comment: i think to pass the selected options into an input type="hidden" field. I'm getting an idea now. thanks for the time. God bless

Answer (score 1):

You can select the text of the selected option using

`var selectedOptions = $('#cols option:selected').text();`

Here is the example,

```js
$('#cols').change(function(){
        var selectedOptions = [];
      $('#cols option:selected').each(function(){
       selectedOptions.push($(this).text());
      });
  alert(selectedOptions);
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="cols" id="cols" multiple>
           <option value"latest_update"> Lates Update</option>
           <option value"spin"> SPIN</option>
           <option value"status"> Status</option>
    </select>
```

Comment: is it possible to past the selected options to the input post? :D

Comment: this won't work on `multiple` ...will be all concatenated together with no delimiter

Comment: is there other way then? :)

Comment: I just modified the script to work with multi dropdown. Now the text will come as an array.

Comment: If you want comma separated string instead of array then add this line above alert statement 

selectedOptions.join(',');